# how to combine all values of an array to form a single variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I have an array which consists on objects with two further nodes, (name , title) the array having product attributes like "size", "style", "colors", etc all these are in a single array. What I want is to create number of dynamic variables basis on attribute "name" and then assign all title values of that specific name to single variable and then move to the next and do the same in JS, following i am sharing the image of an array for better understanding of the structure of my array.

[image]

the code i tried so far, but not successful in that is following too.

```
     var previousValue = a[0].name; 
                  for(var i =0; i < a.length ; i++)
                    { 
                        var currentName = a[i].name; 
                      if(previousValue == currentName) 
                      {
                        var str = a[i].name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                        var sub_var = "var";
                        
                        console.log(sub_var+str);
                        

                      }
                       else{
                        var str = a[i].name.replace(/\s+/g, '');
                        var sub_var = "var";

                        console.log(sub_var+str);
                       }
                      previousValue = currentName; 
                    }
```

here "a" is my array, what it tried to do is to set previous value of name and compare it with current one but it isn't a right way to do it, I'm not getting any successful result from that, the output i require is multiple variables which create dynamically e.g

```
            var Size = M | L | XL | 2XL | 3XL
            var selectyourfit = Regular | Extra Soft | Premium
```

so if someone can help me in that it will be very helpful. Thanks a lot.

Comment: What output you want precisely?

Comment: Please update your question with an example of the array structure that you're looking for if possible to help understand what it is exactly that you want.

Comment: sure let me update it.

Comment: Take a look at my updated question i have mentioned the results what i require in return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should do the trick:

```
const result = YOUR_ARRAY.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const { name, title } = val;
  if (acc[name]) {
    acc[name].push(title)
  } else {
    acc[name] = [title]
  }
  return acc;
}, {})


// Option to display as a string instead of array 

const result = YOUR_ARRAY.reduce((acc, val) => {
  const { name, title } = val;
  if (acc[name]) {
    acc[name] += (` | ${title}` )
  } else {
    acc[name] = title
  }
  return acc;
}, {})
```

Comment: thanks alot, but i have a question it does change it in an object what if i require them as a single value, or we can say merge all titles of attribute and save them inside a single variable as a single string. e.g 
var size = S|M|L|XL;

Comment: or if i can have all titles merge as a single node of objects.

Comment: instead of making array just one string assign to object by merging them.

Comment: I edited the answer to show an option to concat the `title` values

Comment: for example 
Size = Array("S|M|L|XL"); instead of Size= Array("S", "M", "L" , "XL");

Comment: Awesum Lydia thanks alot, you area a real life saver, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const array = [
    {name: "Size", title: "S"},
    {name: "Size", title: "XX"},
    {name: "Size", title: "2XL"},
    {name: "Select Your Fit", title: "Regular"},
    {name: "Select Your Fit", title: "Extra Soft"},
    {name: "Select Your Fit", title: "Premium"}
];


const {Size, 'Select Your Fit': selectyourfit } = array.reduce((acc, {name, title}) => {
    acc[name] = acc[name] ? acc[name]+` | ${title}` : title;
    return acc;
}, {});

console.log("Size : ", Size);
console.log("Select Your Fit : ", selectyourfit)
```